# Infinite Session with facebook ios sdk FBLoginView

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am making my first attempts on FB integration with the iOS SDK.

I have succeeded in establishing a connection with my fb app over the `FBLoginView` which works so far.

Here are my corresponding calls:

```
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
   NSLog(@"logged in");
}
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
   NSLog(@"logged out");
   [FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests, nil]];
   if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
      [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id<FBGraphUser> user,NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
            NSString *fbID = user.id;
            NSLog(@"UserID: %@",fbID);
            NSLog(@"TESTING: %@",user.name);
         }
      }];
   }
}
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
   NSLog(@"Hello %@!", user.first_name);
}
- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error {
   NSLog(@"FBLoginView encountered an error=%@", error);
}
```

i have 1 small and 1 big (topic) question.

**The small**: The request gets fullfilled allright and i get a nice log of it:

```
Response Body:
(
        {
        body =         {
            gender = male;
            id = ###;
            ...
        };
        code = 200;
    }
)
```

But somehow my 2 testlogs dont show, any ideas?

**The big (topic):** I establish that connection in a designated controller in my app. my problem is that on every restart of the app the connection somehow is lost (session not active anymore).. Is there a way to establish an infinite connection using the `FBLoginView`?

I have added the following calls & methods to my appdelegate:

```
//upon start: 
if (![FBSession activeSession].isOpen) {
  [self connectWithFacebook];
}


- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{
   //..  
   return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                             allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                           if (error) {
                                              NSLog (@"Handle error %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                           } else {
                                              [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
                                              [self checkSessionState:state];
                                           }
                                        }];
}
- (void) connectWithFacebook {

   [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
}

- (void) checkSessionState:(FBSessionState)state {
   switch (state) {
      case FBSessionStateOpen:
         break;
      case FBSessionStateCreated:
         break;
      case FBSessionStateCreatedOpening:
         break;
      case FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded:
         break;
      case FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended:
         // I think this is the state that is calling
         break;
      case FBSessionStateClosed:
         break;
      case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}
```

this allows relogin, but every time the app is opened the login screen shows again which is not very userfriendly. Is there a solution to this, and if yes, what am i missing or in what direction could i proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my implementation, keeps the session open for 60 days (maximum allowed time by FB SDK 3.2.1)

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{
    NSArray *readPermissions = @[@"email",@"friends_birthday",@"friends_likes",@"friends_interests",@"user_birthday",@"user_interests",@"user_likes",@"user_location"];

    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:readPermissions
                                                allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                           completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                               FBSessionState state,
                                                               NSError *error) {
                                               [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                   state:state
                                                                   error:error];
                                           }];
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState)state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen: {
            // We have a valid session
            NSLog(@"User session found");
            if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
                [FBRequestConnection
                 startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                   id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                                   NSError *error) {
                        if (!error) {
                            NSLog(@"accessToken: %@ userID: %@",[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken,user.id);
                            self.userID = user.id;
                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:user.first_name  forKey:@"first_name"];
                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:user.last_name  forKey:@"last_name"];
                            NSString *accessToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken;
                            if (accessToken) {
                                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FacebookLoginInProgressNotification object:nil];
                                [self submitFacebookUserID:user.id andAccessToken:accessToken];
                            }
                            else {
                                NSLog(@"no access token for userID: %@",user.id);
                                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FacebookLoginFailureNotification object:nil];
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            //handle error retrieving User ID
                            NSLog(@"error retrieving User ID [%@]",[error localizedDescription]);
                            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FacebookLoginFailureNotification object:nil];
                        }
                 }];
            } else {
                [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
            }

            // Pre-fetch and cache the friends for the friend picker as soon as possible to improve
            // responsiveness when the user tags their friends.
            FBCacheDescriptor *cacheDescriptor = [FBFriendPickerViewController cacheDescriptor];
            [cacheDescriptor prefetchAndCacheForSession:session];
        }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed: {
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed: {
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
     object:session];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Facebook Error %@", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the insight! di am a bit confused about how to connect this with the `FBLoginView`, or should i just use a regular 'homemade' button and connect it with `openSessionWithAllowUI` ?

Comment: I use a 'homemade' button, in iOS 6 this will autoconnect to FB if the user has FB connected in settings.  In iOS 5, it throws up a login window, just saw a stat that said only 11% still on iOS 5, so not a big deal there anyway